# Unable to run Set-AzureDeployment

Tags: deployment, powershell, azure

I'm trying to get my .net website to deploy to azure as part of the TFS Build process. I'm writting a powershell script to do this but I'm getting stuck on the `set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade` command. I'm not sure if there is an easier way but I'm trying to implement the upload based on the code from the windows azure site:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/#step4

When I run the following:

```
Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -SERVICENAME "MYSVC" -Mode Auto -Package D:\MYSVC\Drops\Azure.cspkg -configuration D:\MYSVC\Drops\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg -Slot Staging -Force
```

I get this error:

```
Set-AzureDeployment : The path variable 'SERVICENAME' in the
UriTemplate must be bound to a non-empty string value.
Parameter name:
parameters At line:1 char:20
+ Set-AzureDeployment <<<<  -Upgrade -SERVICENAME "MYSVC" -Mode Auto -Package D:\MYSVC\Drops\Azure.cspkg -Configuration D:\MYSVC\Drops\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg -Slot Staging -Force
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureDeployment], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.HostedServices.SetAzureDeploymentCommand
```

I've checked all the parementers and they are all correct as far as I can tell (the servicename I'm using works when I call `Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName MYSVC`). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using SDK 1.6 or 1.7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to see the exact same problem and after some discussion I found that there is some code issue with this command so when the correct error isn't reported.

Actual the problem is that when you call Set-AzureDeployment, it can not use a Windows Azure Storage Account to temporary upload your package and fail with some weird error.

To solve this problem please **set a valid Windows Azure Storage Account by calling  Set-AzureSubscription first and then use same Set-AzureDeployment command.**

Comment: Cool, I'll give that a try later today and see what happens

Comment: That was the problem. All sorted once I added the Set-AzureDeployment. Thanks for the help